# WebCam over RDP to 2008 and 2016 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2016, rdp

I am unable to use my USB webcam as a local resource when connecting from a windows 10 pc to a 2008 R2 enterprise SP1 server or 2016 Essentials server.

I am able to use a my webcam as a local resource when connecting from windows 10 to another windows 10

On my local machine i have enabled 'Allow RDP redirection of other supported RemoteFX USV devices from this computer' policy setting under Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Connection Client > RemoteFX USB Device Redirection
and then when using RDP changed local resources from 'Video Capture Devices' to 'Other Supported RemoteFX USB Devices' and made sure the camera is checked. I also followed guidance as noted [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd35353f-6056-4249-aaeb-57c6ab2588ae/usb-redirectionremotefx-windows-10-enterprise?forum=win10itprogeneral). Once connected i could still not use the camera. Are there more settings required to enable this?

I have not attempted any fix with the 2016 server as i cannot find any guidance.